# fatal error encountered during command execution mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, fatal-error

I have a Problem during MySQL in C#. I want to search for 4 Keywords in my MySQL Database and when i found an entry my WPF Program display it in a listview but i get always an:

**fatal error encountered during command execution**

here my code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string strName = name.Text;
        string strVorname = vorname.Text;
        string strPLZ = plz.Text;
        string strOrt = ort.Text;

        try
        {


            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=xx.xxx.xxx.xx;Uid=user;Pwd=pw;Database=db;");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Vorname, Plz, FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE @strName AND Vorname LIKE @strVorname AND Plz LIKE @strPLZ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Name", String.Format( "%{0}%", strName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Vorname", String.Format( "%{0}%", strVorname));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plz", String.Format("%{0}%", strPLZ));

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {    
                while (reader.Read())//Lese alle Datensätze aus
                {
                    var getName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));  // 'String aus der Spalte "Name" auslesen
                    MessageBox.Show(getName);                                                         
                }

            }



            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the @Name in the sql query??

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Vorname, Plz FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE @strName AND Vorname LIKE @strVorname AND Plz LIKE @strPlz", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@strName", String.Format( "%{0}%", strName));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@strVorname", String.Format( "%{0}%", strVorname));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPlz", String.Format("%{0}%", strPLZ));
```

Note : Params not surrounded by `'` is correct for them to be treated as params.

Removed a `,` from the query (after Plz)! That was nuts.

Comment: thanks it works! but now i have: " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE %Test% AND Vorname LIKE %TEST

Comment: Okay, so that is against what I thought. Try adding the single quotes around.

Comment: okay, try this : `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@strName", String.Format( "'%{0}%'", strName));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@strVorname", String.Format( "'%{0}%'", strVorname));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPlz", String.Format("'%{0}%'", strPLZ))` `<--` Adding single quotes while providing parameters.

Comment: Single quote should not be before `Select`! It should be around the parameter values. And this should be done while providing the values so that the parameters are identified as parameters.

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Vorname, Plz, FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE '" + ATstrName +"' AND Vorname LIKE '"+ ATstrVorname + "' AND Plz LIKE '" + ATstrPLZ + "'", con); ... is this right now? so i test it but same again

Comment: No, this is not correct. Keep your MySqlCommand as I have indicated in the answer and the parameters as in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399796/fatal-error-encountered-during-command-execution-mysql-c-sharp/25399833?noredirect=1#comment39617633_25399833)

Comment: Single quotes should not be used until parameter evaluation.

Comment: Sry dont understand, i have all in my code what u sayed. 
`MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Vorname, Plz, FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE @strName AND Vorname LIKE @strVorname AND Plz LIKE @strPLZ", con);
               
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strName", String.Format("'%{0}%'", strName));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strVorname", String.Format("'%{0}%'", strVorname));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strPlz", String.Format("'%{0}%'", strPLZ)); `

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL Server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIke '\'%Test%\" AND Vorname LIKE '\'%%\" AND Plz L' at line 1

Comment: Please check the latest updated answer now. There was an extra comma after Plz. This should work.

Comment: Oki now we have no erros. now simply nothing happens. no entry in listview when i klick search button ... nothing happens :D :D

Comment: Do you have any data that matches the query? Run the query in a sqlClient and check if there are any rows returned matching the query.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters names : You can change your snippet like this :

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Vorname, Plz, FROM TBCustomer WHERE Name LIKE '@Name' AND Vorname LIKE '@Vorname' AND Plz LIKE '@Plz' ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Name", String.Format( "%{0}%", strName));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Vorname", String.Format( "%{0}%", strVorname));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plz", String.Format("%{0}%", strPLZ));
```